# Which is best Ajax Framework?

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, ajax.net

I am going to use the ajax for simply refresh the multiple element on the page based on synchronous or asynchronous .
  I want to refresh the page When the ajax request in completed.
  Is there any ajax framework that has ajax utility function ?
  I did not use any javascript framework.
  Now I am developing page based on J2EE.

Comment: Community wiki... These "best" questions never end...

Comment: ...and try marking answers for your previous questions using the TickMark near the answers.

Comment: This is argumentive and also probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) is my choice..Simple, lightweight, cross-browser, easily implementable and has allot of examples everywhere.

Comment: Jquery. Documentation is excellent. And there is JQuery UI which is very nice. Great plugin support also.

Comment: even in the related post, jQuery wins - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798840/what-should-i-choose-jquery-mootools-yui-scriptaculous-or-prototype

Answer (score 0):

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) are generally considered the best ajax javascript frameworks. For a complete list of ajax frameworks go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks).

Answer (score 0):

DWR aka Direct web remoting. Specifically ajax for Java.

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html