# JQuery Vs YUI ? maybe prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, yui

Through the past few years I've been busy with server side programming and I kinda ignored these JavaScript libraries. Because of my good knowledge and long experience with JavaScript I always wrote everything from mostly scratch. Even back then it seemed stupid but I guess it was more the challenge and student mentality. Recently I've started working with YUI, Javascript and Prototype and I easily do what I want however I haven't spent enough time on it and am not sure what I should stick with. I'm planning to use these in a site with 100 users online at a time. So two concerns are efficient AJAX and also client side load time. I am planning to go with the combination of JQuery and YUI. loading Yahoo UI from yahoo and the latter form google. However it seems to me that this is unnecessary and I might in the future regret it.
I wanted to get some opinions! I did look around and read other posts but most people seemed to have an emotional problem rather than technical.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798840/what-should-i-choose-jquery-mootools-yui-scriptaculous-or-prototype

Comment: +1 ...but most people seemed to have an emotional problem rather than technical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs

[Prototype VS jQuery - Strengths and Weaknesses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644556/prototype-vs-jquery)

this next one is a little bit dated but I remember when I was making a similar decision last year this article seemed fairly thorough and symmetrical in it's treatment of pretty much all of the major js frameworks + browsers

http://blog.creonfx.com/javascript/mootools-vs-jquery-vs-prototype-vs-yui-vs-dojo-comparison-revised

I remember this article being decent, but keep in mind he is a rails guy so he's obviously going to like prototype better:

http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2009/01/12/why-i-still-prefer-prototype-to-jquery.html

I went with jquery based mostly on performance.  They use sizzle and seem to be very conscious of the size of their codebase.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not objective about this, but the argument for YUI 3 is that it's concise, efficient, and scalable -- and with 200 modules now in the YUI 3 Gallery, it's got a community making it better every day.

My take on why YUI 3 is the best choice, now about a year old, is here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=miraglia-yuiconf2009-yui3

Since that time, the team has continued to build on the fundamentals discussed there...and YUI 3, for me, is as fun and productive as JavaScript development has ever been.

-Eric

Answer (score 2):

Note that jQuery and YUI are both hosted on googleapis which also offers https whereas Yahoo's CDS does not.

Comment: why would I want to link to it via https?

Comment: If you run any https pages, and link to css/js on a non https site, you will get for *every page* warnings from IE that you are getting a mixture of secure and insecure content.  This is very annoying!

Comment: For production code, best to bundle the library with your own code into a single file anyway, minify it and serve with noodles, sorry gzipped. Rule #1 of client-side performance is reduce the number of requests. Getting these libraries from Google's CDN doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I used YUI extensively on a couple projects and I can say that their online documentation is second to none. Furthermore, the framework is very mature.

I have also started using jQuery recently. So far it also appears to be a fine JavaScript framework.